# ng-repeat not working inside angular-deckgrid

Tags: angularjs, gridview, angularjs-ng-repeat, pinterest

I am Using angular-deckgrid to create pinterest like view

Here is the Code I have written

```
<div deckgrid source="items" class="deckgrid">
    <span  data-ng-repeat='i in card'>{{ i }}</span>
</div>
```

I am expecting the value of i in the ng-repeat, but that seems to be not going in the loop.

Can any one please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 0):

The data-ng-repeat is redundant.  Be default, deckgrid will loop over your items variable and assumes it is an array.

Make sure items is an array and remove the data-ng-repeat.